# Can a string-array be attached to a ListView by default?

Tags: java, android, listview, arrays

If I have a string-array defined in my strings.xml file.

```
<string-array name="items">
    <item >item 1</item>
    <item >item 2</item>
    <item >item 3</item>
</string-array>
```

Could I use a reference to plug it straight into my ListView?

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/itemsListView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    - reference to items here >
</ListView>
```

Or is this only possible using an adapter in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official documentation:

[image]

So use the `android:entries` attribute on your ListView element, pointing to a `<string-array>` resource [ put your array in `res/values/arrays.xml`]

But if you have to customise your items (using ImageView, checkbox...) you have to do it programmatically using cursor adapters or array adapters.

Adapter are an interface between a source of data and ui component each time you have to fill listview, gridview, gallery, spinner etc you have to use adapters

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:entries` for element and refrences your `<string-array>`

and create`(res->value->array.xml)`